# I want to get rid of anything that comes after \ in the following string "Production and nonsupervisory employees\r\n\n\n"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to get rid of characters in a string that comes after \ in python

```
df5['Abbreviation'] = df5['Abbreviation'].str.strip('\')
df5['Data Type'] = df5['Data Type'].str.strip('\')
```

error message:

```
File "<ipython-input-150-c7763a76caaf>", line 1

    df5['Abbreviation'] = df5['Abbreviation'].str.strip('\')
                                                            ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Comment: In the example you provided in the title, all of the characters after `\ ` are whitespace characters, so why not just use `.str.strip()` without any arguments?

Answer (score 4):

You can't have only one `\` (or at the end, or a string with just an odd number of them) in a string literal without escaping it (because it will escape the closing quote), so you must escape it:

```
...str.strip('\\')
```

To remove everything after the backslash, you can use `apply` and `split`:

```
rem = lambda s : s.split('\\')[0] + '\\'

df5['Abbreviation'] = df5['Abbreviation'].apply(rem)
df5['Data Type'] = df5['Data Type'].apply(rem)
```

Also, as @G.Anderson noted, you can use just `...str.strip()` if your strings are like the ones on the title, in this case your code could be:

```
df5['Abbreviation'] = df5['Abbreviation'].apply(str.strip)
df5['Data Type'] = df5['Data Type'].apply(str.strip)
```

Comment: While this does solve the syntax error, it won't solve the actual problem as described (getting rid of all characters _after_ a backslash)

Comment: @G.Anderson Thanks for the note. Now it does.

Comment: +1 from me, but it's worth noting that in the specific posted use case (all the characters to remove are whitespace characters) just using `series.str.strip()` is a bit faster on large datasets

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned with MrGeek's answer, you must escape the backslash.

If you want to remove anything after the backslash, simply do the following:

```
test_str = test_str.str.split('\\')[0]
```

The .split returns an array, and since we only want the contents leading to the first backslash, we can just get the first index using [0].

This will get everything up until the first backslash. If you want to include the backslash, then just append it at the end:

```
test_str = test_str.str.split('\\')[0] + "\\"
```

Comment: Great answer, +1 from me, but note that this is slightly slower than either MrGeek's lambda + apply() answer, and 25% slower than just `series.str.strip()`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `for` loop to iterate in order to strip every character. Here is an example:

```
string = "hit\n"
for i in ['\\n', '\\r']:  string = string.strip(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in MrGeek's answer, you need to add two slashes to fix the initial syntax error. To remove everything after a backslash or special character such as a newline is found, no matter what it is, I found the simplest solution is this:

```
string = "Hello Stack \n\r\rOverflow!"
output = ""
print("In:", string)

for char in string:
    if char == "\\" or char == "\n" or char == "\r":
        break
    else:
        output += char

string = output
print("Out:", string)
```

Which Outputs:

```
In: Hello Stack 
Overflow!
Out: Hello Stack 
>>>
```

This doesn't seem to be the *most* efficient way of doing it, but for small strings like your use case appears to be, the impact is unnoticable and does what is intended.